# Converting characters in XML text node to subscript or superscript with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file structured like this:

```
<Chem>
  
  <Formula>
   CO{2}
  </Formula>
  
  <Name>
   Carbon Dioxide
  </Name>
</Chem>
```

How would I use XSLT to format the number (or all numbers in curly brackets) to subscript?

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "subscript"? Is it some kind of formatting (e.g. a style of HTML output), or do you want to convert the actual characters (e.g. "CO₂")?  Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: XSLT 2 and later have https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#analyze-string, XSLT 3 additionally has https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-analyze-string

Comment: I think analyze-string will work in this instance.  I'm converting the xml into html, so I think I'll try to replace the { } with <sub></sub>.  Thank you for the reply.

Comment: *"I'm converting the xml into html"*. That should have been part of your question - along with the exact expected resulting HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

In **XSLT 2.0** or higher, you could convert all digit characters within curly braces to subscript using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Formula">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\{{(\d+)\}}">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(regex-group(1), '0123456789', '₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉')"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the double escaping of the curly brace characters: first, they are doubled to distinguish them from AVT expressions in XSLT; next, they are preceded by `\` to be interpreted as literal characters in regex.

The **result** using your example input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Chem>
   <Formula>
   CO₂
  </Formula>
   <Name>
   Carbon Dioxide
  </Name>
</Chem>
```

Comment: And to use HTML `<sub>` markup, just change the `translate` line to `<sub><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></sub>`

Comment: @MichaelKay You will need to make additional changes to get proper  HTML result.

Comment: Yes, I was only referring to the local handling of the particular string.

Comment: michael.hor257k - Thank you so much for your criticism!